# Similarity of a Matrix to its Multiple

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ complex matrix. Let $G_M$ be the set of
>   complex numbers $\lambda$ such that the matrix $\lambda M$ is similar to $M$.
>
> What is $G_M$ if
>
> \begin{equation} M = 
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 0  & 4\\
>     0 & 0  & 0\\
> 0 & 0  & 0\\
>   \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation}
>
> Assume $M$ is not nilpotent. Prove $G_M$ is finite.

My Attempt: Let $X \in G_M$, so that X and M are similar if there exists some matrix $D$ such that $MD = DX$.

Letting

\begin{equation} D = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  & c\\
    d & e  & f\\
g & h  & i\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and computing $MD$ and $DX$ we get that

\begin{equation} MD = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    4g & 4h  & 4i\\
    0 & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}
DX = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0  & 4\lambda a\\
    0 & 0  & 4\lambda d\\
0 & 0  & 4\lambda g \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The only restriction I've been able to make it is that $D$ must be nonzero and that $i=4a$.

Comment: This one is quite easy; why not have a go at it yourself before **telling** us to do it?

Comment: Apologies - adding my work for the first part and specifying my main question is the second part.

Comment: Hint: take $D$ to be a diagonal matrix and compute $DMD^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "brute force" method of writing a matrix out completely is rarely the right way to go.

**Hint for part 1:** we should find that $G_M = \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$. To see that this is the case, try computing $X = D^{-1}MD$ where $D$ *is a diagonal matrix*.  Alternatively, note that the Jordan form of $M$ is completely determined from the fact that $M \neq 0$ and $M^2 = 0$.

**Solution for 2:** Note that if $\lambda M$ is similar to $M$, then $\lambda M$ has the same eigenvalues as $M$.  However, if $M$ is not nilpotent, then it has a non-zero eigenvalue.  Now, let $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $M$, and suppose that $\mu_1 \neq 0$.  The eigenvalues of $\lambda M$ are $\lambda \mu_1,\dots,\lambda \mu_n$.  Thus, it must be the case that for some $j = 1,\dots,n$, we have $\lambda \mu_1 = \mu_j$.

However, this would imply that $\lambda = \frac{\mu_j}{\mu_1}$, which gives us only finitely many possibilities.